# In Wordpress: post jQuery variable using AJAX for later use in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In WordPress, I'm trying to post a jQuery variable using AJAX to use later in PHP. I've setup my jQuery function and the function to echo the variable.

I am getting the success message from the jQuery function in the console log, but the $_POST variable is null.

Below are the functions I've setup:

```
function foo_carousel_js() { ?>
     <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
       var count_ci = $('.selector li').length;

       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',   
          url: ajax_url,  
          data: {
            action : 'foo_item_count',
            count_ci : count_ci
          },
          success:function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
          }
       });
    });
   </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'foo_carousel_js' );

function foo_item_count() {

    $k = esc_html( $_POST['count_ci'] );
    echo $k;

    wp_die(); 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_foo_item_count', 'foo_item_count');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foo_item_count', 'foo_item_count');
```

Comment: Did you say `console.log` displays your `count_ci` value correctly in the success callback?

Comment: @TonyM: Yes, it does. I can't figure out how the value is correctly displayed in the console but isn't in the $_POST variable.

Comment: I know this might like a silly question: but how do you know it doesn't? `echo $k;` seems to be working - are you trying to access `$_POST['count_ci'] )` outside of your Ajax handler function? i.e `foo_item_count()`

Comment: @TonyM: What you're asking is helpful--I am trying to access/echo the $_POST variable elsewhere (outside of the handler function), but haven't been able to.

Comment: posted an answer @chowwy, I had this exact problem a while ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same question/problem a few years ago. Turns out you cannot access that Ajax sent value anywhere else within WP besides your functions.php and of course plugin files. Reason being that while *doing* Ajax, WP only reloads the mentioned files (functions and plugins) but not the rest of the template structure. Therefore, while `$_POST` has your data, you can't render it on a template file because those are already loaded.

**Edit**:

Even within the plugin files, you only have access to your `$_POST` values within an Ajax handler function.

I recommend rethinking your goal, maybe Ajax isn't the way to go.

Comment: I actually want to grab the $_POST variable in a plugin template. So are you saying it should be available there?

Comment: I might have been unclear - technically yes but STILL within the handler function. It is not available anywhere else. I'll update my answer to clear that up.

Comment: Ok, so how can I get the variable within the handler function? I've already echoed it out. If I run do_action('ajax_handler_function') it's still not pulling the variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal or the purpose of sending the value is but, you have it: `$k`. You can do operations on it, save it to the db, e.t.c and then `echo` it. e.g you can run query passing `$k` as an argument for a post_id or something. Whatever you're doing has to be done within `foo_item_count() { }`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've accepted and upvoted your answer. I ended up saving the data to the database in my handler function and accessing it that way. Thanks again!